Confused by how ReentrantLock works in Java
Looking at the example comments in the javadoc for Condition. Source
Assuming this scenario :

Thread-1 calls take() on empty buffer
Thread-2 calls put(1) on empty buffer

Timeline :

At t0, Thread-1 acquires the lock at Line 24

At t1, since count==0 goes in busy waiting at L27
As per javadoc at this point, the thread releases the lock and goes into dormant.

At t2, Thread-2 acquires the lock in put at line 10

At t3, the thread executes until Line 17, which signals the Thread-1


Since Thread-2 never got to a point to release its lock (line 19) what happens at time t3, does the Thread-1 can execute? Which would break the contract that only one thread is allowed to execute ReentrantLock at a time?
1 class BoundedBuffer<E> {
2    final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
3    final Condition notFull  = lock. newCondition(); 
4    final Condition notEmpty = lock. newCondition(); 
5 
6    final Object[] items = new Object[100];
7    int putptr, takeptr, count;
8 
9    public void put(E x) throws InterruptedException {
10      lock. lock();
11      try {
12        while (count == items. length)
13          notFull. await();
14        items[putptr] = x;
15        if (++putptr == items. length) putptr = 0;
16        ++count;
17        notEmpty. signal();
18      } finally {
19        lock. unlock();
20      }
21    }
22 
23    public E take() throws InterruptedException {
24      lock. lock();
25      try {
26        while (count == 0)
27          notEmpty. await();
28        E x = (E) items[takeptr];
29        if (++takeptr == items. length) takeptr = 0;
30        --count;
31        notFull. signal();
32        return x;
33      } finally {
34        lock. unlock();
35      }
36    }
37  }



Also mentioned in the Javadoc for Condition#await. It says, "In all cases, before this method can return the current thread must re-acquire the lock associated with this condition."

Moved my comments to an answer (and included the documentation referenced by @Solomon).

No, the mutual-exclusion guarantees of ReentrantLock are not violated when a thread blocked on await() is signaled. Such a thread cannot return from await() until it reacquires the lock, which only one thread can hold at any given time. In other words, the earliest a signaled thread can return from await() is just after the thread that invoked signal() releases the lock.

Documentation
Condition#await()

Causes the current thread to wait until it is signalled or interrupted.
The lock associated with this Condition is atomically released and the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until one of four things happens:

Some other thread invokes the signal() method for this Condition and the current thread happens to be chosen as the thread to be awakened; or
Some other thread invokes the signalAll() method for this Condition; or
Some other thread interrupts the current thread, and interruption of thread suspension is supported; or
A "spurious wakeup" occurs.

In all cases, before this method can return the current thread must re-acquire the lock associated with this condition [emphasis added]. When the thread returns it is guaranteed to hold this lock.
[...]

Condition#signal()

Wakes up one waiting thread.
If any threads are waiting on this condition then one is selected for waking up. That thread must then re-acquire the lock before returning from await [emphasis added].
[...]

